# Laravel 8.6 firstOrCreate on variable model from URL

Tags: laravel, datatable, model, find

In a URL i pass the table name with the where parameters en map this using a JSON. The problem is now is. I use `DB::table($table)` but this doesn't allow `firstOrCreate` so i wanted to try it by model, but $table::were doesn't see $table as a model name. Even if i change it from 'establisments' to 'Estalishment'. Maybe i need to put `App\` before it? Because the model is not in `use`. How can i get the object using a model from model names as in the URL?

URL:

```
&spec_code=CHI&department=surgery&department_code=SUR
```

JSON:

```
{
  "establishments": { // $table name, but want it to be model)
    "from1": "spec_code", // from url
    "to1": "abc_id" // to column in database
  },
  "departments": {
    "from1": "department",
    "to1": "name",
    "from2": "department_code",
    "to2": "abc_id"
  },
}
```

Controller:

```
foreach(JSON as $table => $field){
if(isset($field['from2'])){
       $output[$table] = DB::table($table)->where($field['to1'], $request->input($field['from1']))->where($field['to2'], $request->input($field['from2']))->first();
}elseif(isset($field['from1'])){
       $output[$table] = DB::table($table)->where($field['to1'], $request->input($field['from1']))->first();
//     $output[$table] = $table::where($field['to1'], $request->input($field['from1']))->firstOrCreate(); //i want this.
//     $output[$table] = "\App\\".$table::where($field['to1'], $request->input($field['from1']))->firstOrCreate();
}else{
      $output[$table] = null;
}
}
```

If someone knows how i can get it to use the model so i can firstOrCreate(), that would make my code a lot cleaner.

Kind regards,
Jeff

Comment: firstOrCreate it's an Eloquenf method, so you have to use it with a model. In your case you can use `$class = "App\Models\{$table}"; $class::firstOrCreate(....);` $table should match the name of your model, so for instance, $table = "User"; for App\Models\User

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.
Create an array using which you can get model

```php
$models = [
  'establishments' => \App\Models\Establishment::class,
  'departments' => \App\Models\Department::class,
]
```

Then within loop you can get the model from the array using

```php
foreach(JSON as $table => $field){
   $models[$table]::firstOrCreate(/* */)
}
```

As i said there are many ways to fulfill your requirement. this is one way i would do.

Comment: I tried this a little differt, because $models is hard coded in your example. I Tried to make it variable: 
$class = "\App\\".$table."::class";
$output[$table] = $class::firstOrCreate($field['to1'], $request->input($field['from1']));

But i get Class not found error.

Comment: dd($class) = "\App\Establishment::class" (older version of laravel so no \Models\)

Comment: Lets say you have a table `order_products` you need to convert this string to model name which could be `OrderProd` in this way you cannot make a code which can pick correct class.

Comment: there is an other automated way, which is using `Str` class, check this example  \Illuminate\Support\Str::of('establishments')->singular()->headline()->remove(' ');  --- this will return `Establishment` so you can use this algo to fetch class name from string

Comment: Ah! I think it finds the firstOrCreate. I get an error "Argument 1 passed" with this code
                        $class = "\App\\".$table;
                        $output[$table] = $class::firstOrCreate($field['to1'], $request->input($field['from1'])); We are getting closer!

Comment: `firstOrCreate` needs 2 arrays, use something like this `firstOrCreate([ 'email' => 'demo@gmail.com' ], ['name' => 'Demo']);`   it will check if user with email exists then update `name` else create the record with `name & email`

Answer (score 0):

By Default laravel does't have out of the box method to get the Model `FQN` based on the table name.

Because you can have model under different namespace.

But however you can do a workaround

```
$tableClassToFind = 'users';
    $models = [
        \App\Models\User::class,
        //add your model(s) here
    ];

   $modelClass =  collect($models)
    ->map(function($eachModelFqn){
        return [
            'modelClass' => $eachModelFqn,
            'tableName' => app($eachModelFqn)->getTable(),
        ];
    })
    ->mapWithKeys(fn($value) => [$value['tableName'] => $value['modelClass']])
    ->get($tableClassToFind);

    dd($modelClass);
```

Basically it will get all the table name along with the Model `FQN` and changing the value of `$tableClassToFind` will get the appropriate Model class.

Please all the models to `$models` variable.